# Android Java jSON UTF-8 httpResponse Problems

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, utf-8

I've got a problem with german characters in utf-8. I work with a MySQL database from which I'll get my data with PHP. The php script converts the data into a json object and sent it to the application. The database contains doubles and strings. First the application send a string with the name of a topic. The php search in the db for the topic, convert the content into a json and send it to the application.

I tried to sent the data without characters like "ä,ü,ö" and it work. When I'm using this german characters it stop on line

```
HttpResponse response =httpClient.execute(httppost);
```

I don't know why and what I'm doing wrong.
Here is my application code:

```
public void getData(String data){
        String topic = data; //Parameter for PHP
        String result = "";
        InputStream isr = null;
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); //PHP
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("topic", topic)); //PHP

        try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.179.20:80/PHP/getData.php");  //PHP-Script on localhost
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); //PHP
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();

    } 
    catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            resultView.setText("Could not connect to database");
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();

            result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result "+e.toString());
    }


   try {
       String s = "";
       JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

       for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
           JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);



           double Lat = json.getDouble("Latitude");
           double Lng = json.getDouble("Longitude");
           String Title = new String(json.getString("Ueberschrift").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
           String ShortText = new String(json.getString("Kurzbeschreibung").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
           String LongText = new String(json.getString("Inhalt").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
           String Thema = new String(json.getString("Thema").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
           String Datum = json.getString("Date");
           String Url = new String(json.getString("Url").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");

           s = s +
                   "Latitude: "+Lat+", "+"Longitude: "+Lng+"\n"+
                   "Thema: "+Thema+"\n"+
                   "Titel: "+Title+"\n"+
                   "Kurzbezeichnung: "+ShortText+"\n"+
                   "Inhalt: "+LongText+"\n\n";


       }


       resultView.setText(s);

   } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
       Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
   }

    }
```

Here a part of my php:

```
 mysql_select_db("database", $con);
       mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
      $thema = $_REQUEST['topic'];


       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE Thema='$thema'") or die('Errant query:');


       while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
       {

       $output[]=$row;

       }
       //$output = serialize($output);       
       //$output = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $output);

    if (function_exists('json_encode')) 
    {
        echo json_encode($output);
        echo "JSON Error: ".json_last_error();
    }
    else { echo "json_encode() is not supported"; }


       mysql_close($con);
```

The json looks like this:

```
[{"id":"5","Longitude":"11.0730833333333","Latitude":"49.4530833333333","Height":"10","Ueberschrift":"Henkersteg","Kurzbeschreibung":"Der Henkersteg, auch","Inhalt":"Stadtbefestigung\u00a0| Marthakirch","Thema":"D\u00fcrer","Thema_id":"3","Datetime":"15\/02\/2015","Url":"http:\/\/de.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Henkersteg"}]JSON Error: 0
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So you have problems posting these characters. Start with changing your php script. Do nothing with the database. Instead just echo the received data.. Test if you get those characters back first. Do not json encode in php either.

Comment: Don't let it go to "unicode" such as `\u00a0`.  You probably need utf8, instead.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the line

```
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

to

```
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

I changed also the settings of my database. After changed them, I could display my string in the application, but unfortunately I get a "?" instead of a "ü".

Comment: Is the rest of the string missing after the "?"?  (This could be an important clue.)

Comment: No, only the character is displayed as "?". The rest of the string is printed correctly. (For example: D?rer instead of Dürer)